# Python / PostgreSQL - How to copy a table to another using the psycopg2 library?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm writing the code in Python and am using the psycopg2 library to deal with my PostgreSQL database.

I have the table `Orders` with about 30 rows. I want to copy this entire table to an empty one with the same structure called `Orders2`.

How can I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your own answer is correct, there is a better way that does not involve dumping to a file and is generally more flexible.

```
INSERT INTO orders2 SELECT * FROM orders
```

Answer (score 8):

The answer is:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extensions import ISOLATION_LEVEL_SERIALIZABLE
import sys
import cStringIO

con = psycopg2.connect(database="xxxx", user="xxxx", password="xxxx", host="localhost")
cur = con.cursor()

input = cStringIO.StringIO()
cur.copy_expert('COPY (select * from Orders) TO STDOUT', input)
input.seek(0)
cur.copy_expert('COPY Orders2 FROM STDOUT', input)
con.commit()
```

Comment: This is great for copying table to a different DB, just have two connections.